# What is C-terminal tryptic peptide?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protein-structure

A biologist wrote to me:

`... C- or N-terminus,... For example, a C-terminal tryptic peptide like AGWRGSDSHSR, would be...`

I don't have any idea what that is. When I google the term ("C-terminal tryptic peptide"), nothing obvious came up. What's that? Why `AGWEGSDSHSR` is a "C-terminal tryptic peptide"?

Comment: Did a biologist really write this to you? Seems strange as it's clearly not your field. But really how do you expect a decent answer unless you give us the full text and context of what appears to me as a quite bizarre communication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its quite simple if you look at the basics! Lets have a look at the sequence you give:

> AGWRGSDSHSR

Write that in 3-letter terms<sup>[1](http://www.fao.org/docrep/004/Y2775E/y2775e0e.htm)</sup>:

> Ala-Gly-Trp-Arg-Gly-Ser-Asp-Ser-His-Ser-Arg

Pay attention to the C-terminus. The last amino acid residue in the sequence is Arginine. Now, its well established that Trypsin cleaves a polypeptide *after* (i.e. towards the C-terminal side of) Lysine and Arginine<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypsin)</sup>.

Thus, C-terminal tryptic peptide is the peptide that remains after a polypeptide has been treated with Trypsin.

Comment: Its just about getting the clues @smallchess

Comment: Ah, so it refers to where the peptide was cleaved, not where the peptide was located on the original protein. Unintuitive for me :)

Comment: @armatus haha I've been working on peptide sequencing for a while now, so I got the point there ;)

Comment: Why the downvote? I get that the question is pretty naive, but is there something wrong in the answer?

Comment: Trypsin does not cleave at the "carboxy-terminus" of any amino acid, as that term is used to designate one end of a protein (that with a free alpha-COOH). I also do not believe "C-terminal lysis by trypsin" means anything, or if it did it would mean the removal of the C-terminal amino acid, which is here not the case. Your answer does not represent usage and is clearly wrong.

Comment: @david I agree with you in that I should have framed my sentences more carefully since there are terms which represent something but are used to mean something else. I've edited my answer. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: @xusr yup I get what you mean, so I edited the answer a bit to make it clearer :)

Comment: Downvotes are free that is why instead of giving input to improve the answer people go around anon downvoting.

Comment: @ronisaiba TBH I quite agree with you. Most of the time David has something to say about my answer, I see him talking like "here's a -1 and a comment for you". AFAIK what SE encourages is "all right you touch the correct point, lemme just edit these finer details to make it more presentable". Downvotes on answers do give -1 to downvoter though :/

Answer (score 4):

Unless your corespondent is off their rocker (or I am), this is rather unambiguously referring to the peptide released from the C-terminal end of a polypeptide by tryptic digestion.

This means that the final arginine in your sequence would have been the C-terminus of the original polypeptide, not the trypsin cleavage site. It also means that your sequence was preceded by R or K.

Comment: Quite, which is why it looks like some sort of homework question, with the R in the sequence as red herring.